# Использование ios без использования системного кэша(Windows)

Tags: c++, windows

По умолчанию ios(ostream, istream) для чтения и записи используют системный кэш. 
У меня возник вопрос, если возможность запретить ios использовать системный кэш?
Просто, в дальнейшем я хочу что бы ios работал с моим собственный буфером в качестве кэша.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да можно попробовать. Сначала надо открыть файл с флагом `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, этот флаг заставляет диспетчер кэша не выполнять кэширование для этого файла. Затем получить сишный хэндл и создать `ifstream` для него:

```
{
   HANDLE win_handle = CreateFile
   (
        "file.name"
       , GENERIC_READ
       , NULL
       , OPEN_EXISTING
       , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING
       , NULL
   );

   if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != win_nandle)
   {
       int std_handle = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)win_handle, _O_RDONLY);
       if(std_handle >= 0)
       {
          FILE * f = _fdopen(std_handle, "r");
          if(f)
          {
             std::ifstream stream(f);

             // устанавливаем свой буфер
             // и работаем с потоком

             stream.close();
             fclose(f);                 
          }
          _close(std_handle);
       }
       CloseHandle(win_handle);
   }       
}
```

Comment: Это если использовать WinAPI. А я хотел попробовать сделать это через ios.

Comment: @ВалентинЧикунов через ios не получится так как диспетчер кэша работает на уровне ядра, обойти его не получится он используется по-умлочанию

Comment: А если установить буфер ios равным нулю?

Comment: Хорошо, проверьте самостоятельно отключается или нет.